# How to get the TFS build repository url?

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am new to TFS. However, I have created a new TFS Account in Visual Studio and under visual studio 2013, I have created a new team project checked in. However, when I am trying to create a new job in jenkins, I am not able to file the Url for the repository of my solution that I have build. My code is under the url:

https://himanshuaccount.visualstudio.com/Himanshu_Workspace/_versionControl?path=%24%2FHimanshu_Workspace%2FTFS%20Information%2FTFSApplication1&version=T&_a=contents

The repository url is not being taken by jenkins. Any idea where I can find my TFS repository url in Visual Studio 2013 or under Microsoft Account?

Comment: Have you added the Jenkins service hook? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/services/jenkins

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable alternate credentials in your Visual Studio Team Services profile. Be sure to set a secondary user name because you won't be able to use your email account to connect Visual Studio Team Services to Jenkins.
2. Go to your team project's administration page. On the Service Hooks tab, create a subscription and add Jenkins.

[image]

[image]

3. Pick the event from Visual Studio Team Services that you want to trigger a Jenkins build. Configure the action to take in Jenkins.

[image]

4. In Jenkins, create a new item. Create the type of build that's appropriate for your project.
5. Set the URL for your TFVC repository in Visual Studio Team Services. Details: https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin

[image]